# Before getting data from database, renderview is getting called in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactive-programming

In my project, we are using promises to fetch data from DB. Before data returned, the renderView() method is getting called multiple times. In this process, as per below code, else part is displaying and disappearing in the renderView method cycles. In this renderView method, we are making a check that 
`if(recordsArray.length > 0) 
   render view of records
 else 
    display that records are not there`

At the point of if condition, in few cycles, the recordsArray length is 0 and after few cycles, recordsArray is getting filled. 
Is there any way to call renderView after recordsArray get filled?

Comment: Show us all of your code, we can't fix it, or give a good solution unless you do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ortho Home Defense's comment, if we don't see whole or related code we can't help you very much. But as far as I understood if you don't want to invoke your renderView function many times you need to check your data somehow and then invoke it. This means a change in your logic like:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>{recordsArray.length && renderView()}</div>
      );
  }

renderView = () { ...render data }
```

Like this nothing will be rendered until your data is filled. If you want to show something you can use ternary operator.

```
render() {
        return (
          <div>{!recordsArray.length ? <p>No data</p> : renderView()}</div>
          );
      }
```